# Passport js always shows Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am new to nodejs(v4.5) & express(v4) and i am trying to create login with passport js(local) . i tried a lot but i always get 401 error. I also checked forums but could not find the solution.
Express-session is v1.5.

This is my code:
app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');

var base = require('./base');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'vidyapathaisalwaysrunning',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
 } ));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.rooturl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')  + '/';
    next();
});

require('./routes/admin')(app, passport); 
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}



// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

db.js

```
var mysql   = require('mysql');
var sqlConnection = function sqlConnection(sql, values, next) {
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        next = values;
        values = null;
    }

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    port: 3306,
    database : 'test'
  });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err !== null) {
            console.log("[MYSQL] Error connecting to mysql:" + err+'\n');
        }
    });

    connection.query(sql, values, function(err) {
        connection.end();
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        // Execute the callback
        next.apply(this, arguments);
    });
}

module.exports = sqlConnection;
```

admin.js

```
var db = require('../config/db');
module.exports = function(app, passport){
  app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login/admin', {
        rooturl: req.rooturl,
        title: 'Crud'
    });
  });

  app.post('/admin', passport.authenticate('local-login'), function(req, res) {
      res.json('5');
  });  
};
```

admin.ejs

```
$('#login').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form){
            var data  = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url: document.url,
                //data: new FormData(form),
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(d){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(d));
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-localapikey').Strategy;
var db = require('./db');

module.exports = function(passport) {
   // console.log('5');
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log('4');
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        db("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
            console.log('6');
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
    });
    passport.use('local-login',
        new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true 
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            console.log(username);
            db("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? and password = ?",[username, password], function(err, rows){
                console.log('2');
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (!rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); 
                }

                if(password != rows[0].password){
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));
                }
                return done(null, rows[0]);
            });
        })
    );
}
```